# Some advice about REST endpoints design

Tags: java, rest, media-type

Currently we have some endpoints which are essentialy a PATCH but the request is to not leverage on JSONPatch o JSONMergePatch objects because endpoints must have specific DTOs as body.
My idea is to have the same `@PATCH` endpoint consumes different types:

```
@Path("path/to/resource")
@PATCH
@Consumes(???)
void modificationOne(DTO#1 modifications) {
}

@Path("path/to/resource")
@PATCH
@Consumes(???)
void modificationTwo(DTO#2 modifications) {
}
```

I'm struggle about `@Consumes()` media type:

- `application/vnd.patch.modificationOne+json`, `application/vnd.patch.modificationTwo+json`
- `application/json-patch+json; type=DTO#1`, `application/json-patch+json; type=DTO#2`

Anyone with some advices for a better and/or more pratical solution?

Comment: This is a FANTASTIC question; but I don't know of any authorities beyond RFC 9110 and RFC 6838, both of which you seem to have already discovered and reviewed.  My guess is that differences in schema should be indicated by differences in subtype, rather than differences in parameters.

Comment: I'm a little bit more confident that +json-patch is a bad idea, because json-patch is not a registered structured syntax suffix.  See https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-type-structured-suffix/media-type-structured-suffix.xhtml

Comment: I used the `+json-patch` to made evidence that `application/vnd.patch.modificationTwo` is used for patch (`application/json-patch+json`) but after reading your link you are absolutely right. Thanks!