# How to implement @PATCH method (REST) in Quarkus

Tags: java, rest, quarkus, resteasy

I want to implement a REST-Method (@PATCH) to update some fields of an entity and took this documentation as reference: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.6.0.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e1781

But I always get the response 400 (bad request)

My steps to create a sample application:

1. loaded a starter project from quarkus.io (quarkus version 2.15.3.Final) with dependency to 'quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson'
2. added a class 'User'

```
package org.acme;

import java.util.Objects;

public class User {

  Integer id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  public Integer getId() {return id;}
  public void setId(Integer id) {this.id = id;}
  public String getFirstName() {return firstName;}
  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {this.firstName = firstName;}
  public String getLastName() {return lastName;}
  public void setLastName(String lastName) {this.lastName = lastName;}

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("User [ id: %d ]", Objects.requireNonNullElse(id, -1));
  }
}
```

3. changed 'GreetingsResource.java' to this:

```
package org.acme;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PATCH;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.RestPath;

@Path("/user")
public class GreetingResource {


    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/{id}")
    public User getUser(Integer id) {
      User user = new User();
      user.id = 1;
      user.firstName = "John";
      user.lastName = "Doe";

      // return Response.noContent();
      return user;
    }

    @PATCH
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_PATCH_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User patchUser(@RestPath("id") Integer id, User user) {
      return user;
    }
}
```

4. fetched User data from the get endpoint using SoapUI, everything works as expected

```
GET http://localhost:8080/user/1 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.1)
```

5. Try to patch the user (using SoapUI), got response code of 400 (Bad Request)

```
PATCH http://localhost:8080/user/1 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json
Content-Length: 53
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.1)

[{"op":"replace","path":"/lastName","value":"Smith"}]
```

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
content-length: 0
```

After changing the log level to 'debug' I see the following error:

```
2023-01-13 12:45:57,049 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.rea.ser.han.RequestDeserializeHandler] (executor-thread-0) Error occurred during deserialization of input: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `org.acme.User` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
 at [Source: (org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

So for me it looks like the application awaits a document describing a User and no patch request like I sent. But as far I understand the documentation, mentioned at the beginning of this post, the framework should automatically patch the existing user with the patch from the request. The input parameter of the @PATCH method should then hold the User instance that is already patched.

Any ideas or hints what I'm doing wrong? Do I expect things that will not work this way?

In case this is important: I'm running the application on a Windows host using this Java version:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.2 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-86)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-86, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74994351/some-advice-about-rest-endpoints-design

Comment: Your endpoint is setup to accept a `User`, but you send a JSON patch request. Those don't match. Either change the argument type to something that matches JSON patch requests, or change the request. In the latter case, the custom is to overwrite any non-`null` value, and ignore any `null` value.

Comment: @RobSpoor I see your point regarding the parameter types. But I followed the documentation I mentioned before and they do it the same way (as long as I missed nothing). see:  https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.6.0.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e1781
So I assumed the endpoint applies the patch before my method is called and I should get a User already patched. What do you think? Do I missunderstood the linked document?

Comment: @vizete I think so. Just above the code snippet is a second request with this body: `{"firstName":"Green","school":null}`. That matches the second approach. The `null` here indicates that the field should be unset, but that's often troublesome in code because in most JSON mapping frameworks there is no difference between an absent field and a field explicitly set to `null`.